# pipe stdout and stderr to two different processes in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, io-redirection

I've a pipline doing just

```
 command1 | command2
```

So, stdout of command1 goes to command2 , while stderr of command1 go to the terminal (or wherever stdout of the shell is).

How can I pipe stderr of command1 to a third process (`command3`) while stdout is still going to command2 ?

Comment: Have a look at [my answer to *Pipe output to two different commands*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13108173/1765658) and [my *Intro about parallelisation*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19125525/1765658)!

Answer (score 82, accepted):

### Use another file descriptor

```
{ command1 2>&3 | command2; } 3>&1 1>&2 | command3
```

You can use up to 7 other file descriptors: from 3 to 9.
If you want more explanation, please ask, I can explain ;-)

### Test

```
{ { echo a; echo >&2 b; } 2>&3 | sed >&2 's/$/1/'; } 3>&1 1>&2 | sed 's/$/2/'
```

output:

```
b2
a1
```

### Example

Produce two log files:
 1. `stderr` only
 2. `stderr` and `stdout`

```
{ { { command 2>&1 1>&3; } | tee err-only.log; } 3>&1; } > err-and-stdout.log
```

If `command` is `echo "stdout"; echo "stderr" >&2` then we can test it like that:

```
$ { { { echo out>&3;echo err>&1;}| tee err-only.log;} 3>&1;} > err-and-stdout.log
$ head err-only.log err-and-stdout.log
==> err-only.log <==
err

==> err-and-stdout.log <==
out
err
```

Comment: How do you add a file descriptor?  `echo out >&3` outputs "-bash: 3: Bad file descriptor"

Comment: Found the answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18899/when-would-you-use-an-additional-file-descriptor

Comment: antak's answer below is more complete.  It still maintains the original separation between stdout and stderr as the command does without all the pipes.  Note that with pipes, command is run in a subprocess.  If you don't want that, for you may want the command to modify global variables, you would need to create fifo and use redirections instead.

Comment: Thanks, @oHo. BTW, is there a way to preserve the `command`'s exit code, esp. given the `tee` eats it up. I.e. a next command `rc=$?` saves `0` to `rc`.

Answer (score 59):

The accepted answer results in the reversing of `stdout` and `stderr`.  Here's a method that preserves them (since Googling on that purpose brings up this post):

```
{ command 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | stderr_command; } 3>&1 1>&2 | stdout_command
```

Notice:

- `3>&-` is required to prevent *fd 3* from being inherited by `command`.  (As this can lead to unexpected results depending on what `command` does inside.)

#### Parts explained:

1. Outer part first:

   1. `3>&1` -- *fd 3* for `{ ... }` is set to what *fd 1* was (i.e. `stdout`)
   2. `1>&2` -- *fd 1* for `{ ... }` is set to what *fd 2* was (i.e. `stderr`)
   3. `| stdout_command` -- *fd 1* (was `stdout`) is piped through `stdout_command`
2. Inner part inherits file descriptors from the outer part:

   1. `2>&1` -- *fd 2* for `command` is set to what *fd 1* was (i.e. `stderr` as per outer part)
   2. `1>&3` -- *fd 1* for `command` is set to what *fd 3* was (i.e. `stdout` as per outer part)
   3. `3>&-` -- *fd 3* for `command` is set to nothing (i.e. *closed*)
   4. `| stderr_command` -- *fd 1* (was `stderr`) is piped through `stderr_command`

### Example:

```
foo() {
    echo a
    echo b >&2
    echo c
    echo d >&2
}

{ foo 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | sed -u 's/^/err: /'; } 3>&1 1>&2 | sed -u 's/^/out: /'
```

#### Output:

```
out: a
err: b
err: d
out: c
```

(Order of `a -> c` and `b -> d` will always be indeterminate because there's no form of synchronization between `stderr_command` and `stdout_command`.)

Comment: This thing works, I verified it but I am not able to understand how it works. In the outer part, Point 3 stdout_command isn't fd1 now pointing to stderr, how is stdout going there instead of stderr.

Comment: Infact this also worked (command 2>&1 | stderr_command; ) 1>&2 | stdout_command

Comment: @RahulKadukar That puts both `stdout` and `stderr` of `command` through `stderr_command` and nothing goes through `stdout_command`.

Comment: I enjoyed unraveling this, thank you (: Note: you could make it a little shorter by having the innermost redirects be merely `2>&3 3>&-`. This does, however, mean you need to handle stdout on the inside of the curlies and stderr on the outside (so, swap `stdin_command` and `stdout_command` in your example).

Comment: @jwd Thanks for the comment. :)  Problem with that approach is `stdout` and `stderr` of the entire command line comes out reversed.  I tested it by adding `>/dev/null` on the end of the command line and seeing if only `a` and `c` were filtered out.

Comment: Oh good point. And I guess there's no easy way to get around that since the outermost pipe will write to the shell's `stdout` regardless of redirects (unless we added more curlies). No golf points for me (:

Comment: This is great, thanks @antak!  But I found that while it works great in bash, it doesn't work as-is in zsh due to multios.  I posted a tweaked version for zsh as [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59638811/2562319).

Comment: My quick’n’dirty go-to for stuff like this (particularly when I’m just typing — and thinking — left-to-right at an interactive shell) has usually been something along the lines of `{ cmd 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- | tee err.log; } 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&- | tee out.log` (swap out/err, process err; swap again, process out…) but the succinctity of this is quite appealing, and I suspect it’s more efficient to boot, since it allows the subshell to inherit the temporary file descriptor (as subprocesses were designed to do) instead of taking pains to recreate it unnecessarily… I may have to start using this. :)

Answer (score 32):

Using process substitution:

```
command1 > >(command2) 2> >(command3)
```

See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html for more info.

Comment: Note: this is not POSIX but a bashism.

Comment: It's also so much nicer than the POSIX solutions.

Comment: This does not work. Using the example `foo` function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31151808, the output of `foo > >(sed -u 's/^/out: /') 2> >(sed -u 's/^/err: /')` is `out: a`  `out: c` `out: err: b` `out: err: d`

Comment: Interestingly, reversing the order *does* work. `foo 2> >(sed -u 's/^/err: /') > >(sed -u 's/^/out: /')` outputs `err: b` `err: d` `out: a` `out: c`

Comment: Hi @ClementCherlin, the order of 1> and 2> shouldn't matter:
`$ mkdir -v test > >(sed 's/^/OUT: /') 2> >(sed 's/^/ERR: /')
OUT: mkdir: created directory ‘test’
$ mkdir -v test > >(sed 's/^/OUT: /') 2> >(sed 's/^/ERR: /')
OUT: ERR: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: File exists
$ rmdir test
$ mkdir -v test 2> >(sed 's/^/ERR: /') > >(sed 's/^/OUT: /')
OUT: mkdir: created directory ‘test’
$ mkdir -v test 2> >(sed 's/^/ERR: /') > >(sed 's/^/OUT: /')
ERR: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: File exists`

Are you sure about which output of `foo` is goint to STDOUT/STDERR?

Comment: Maybe an easier example:
`$ (echo out >&1; echo err >&2) 1> >(sed 's/^/OUT: /') 2> >(sed 's/^/ERR: /')
$ OUT: out
OUT: ERR: err

$ (echo out >&1; echo err >&2) 2> >(sed 's/^/ERR: /') 1> >(sed 's/^/OUT: /')
$ ERR: err
OUT: out`

Comment: @FuePi do you see in your own output `OUT: out OUT: ERR: err`? That's the problem. `err` is being processed by the `ERR` script, and then the output of the `ERR` script is going to the `OUT` script.

Comment: Hi @ClementCherlin, that is due to echo adding a newline. Try this: `(echo -n out >&1; echo err >&2) 1> >(sed 's/^/OUT: /') 2> >(sed 's/^/ERR: /')`
The output is for me:  `OUT: outERR: err`

Comment: @FuePi Unfortunately, it's not related to echo, it's the order of redirections. `(printf out >&1; printf err >&2) 1> >(sed 's/^\(.\+\)$/FIRST<\1>/') 2> >(sed 's/^\(.\+\)$/SECOND[\1]/')` produces `FIRST<outSECOND[err]>`, but `(printf out >&1; printf err >&2) 2> >(sed 's/^\(.\+\)$/FIRST<\1>/') 1> >(sed 's/^\(.\+\)$/SECOND[\1]/')` produces `SECOND[out]FIRST<err>`

Answer (score 16):

### Simply redirect stderr to stdout

```
{ command1 | command2; } 2>&1 | command3
```

**Caution:** `commnd3` will also read `command2` stdout (if any).
To avoid that, you can discard `commnd2` stdout:

```
{ command1 | command2 >/dev/null; } 2>&1 | command3
```

However, to keep `command2` stdout (e.g. in the terminal), 
then please refer to my other answer more complex.

### Test

```
{ { echo -e "a\nb\nc" >&2; echo "----"; } | sed 's/$/1/'; } 2>&1 | sed 's/$/2/'
```

output:

```
a2
b2
c2
----12
```

Comment: Whoops, good call. I intially thought the OP wanted stderr to go *only* to `command 3`. This looks like the right way to go.

Comment: Wouldn't `{ command1 | command2 >/dev/null 2>&1 } 2>&1 | command3 ` prevent stdout/stderr of command2 to reach command3 , or would that also mess with stderr of command1 ?

Comment: Hi @user964970. The `/dev/null` redirection is a good idea. As you said, your example above mess `stderr` and `stdout` because they are inverted in the same step. I would prefer `{ command1 | command2 >/dev/null; } 2>&1 | command3`. I edit my answer to use your brilliant contribution. Thanks ;-)

Comment: One problem with this answer is that the { } creates a subshell, which in some situations is not acceptabe. For instance, you cannot pass variables back out of the {}.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe stdout as usual, but use Bash process substitution for the stderr redirection:

```
some_command 2> >(command of stderr) | command of stdout
```

Header: `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 2):

## Zsh Version

I like the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31151808/2562319) posted by @antak, but it doesn't work correctly in zsh due to multios.  Here is a small tweak to use it in zsh:

```
{ unsetopt multios; command 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | stderr_command; } 3>&1 1>&2 | stdout_command
```

To use, replace `command` with the command you want to run, and replace `stderr_command` and `stdout_command` with your desired pipelines.  For example, the command `ls / /foo` will produce both stdout output and stderr output, so we can use it as a test case.  To save the stdout to a file called stdout and the stderr to a file called stderr, you can do this:

```
{ unsetopt multios; ls / /foo 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | cat >stderr; } 3>&1 1>&2 | cat >stdout
```

See @antak's original answer for full explanation.

Comment: This worked in zsh for me, except stderr and stdout commands were flipped for me. Both bash and zsh. It looks like to me you are redirecting stdout to 3, then routing 3 back to stdout, so the last statement should be to stdout. I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

The same effect can be accomplished fairly easily with a fifo. I'm not aware of a direct piping syntax for doing it (though it would be nifty to see one). This is how you might do it with a fifo.

First, something that prints to both `stdout` and `stderr`, `outerr.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This goes to stdout"
echo "This goes to stderr" >&2
```

Then we can do something like this:

```
$ mkfifo err
$ wc -c err &
[1] 2546
$ ./outerr.sh 2>err | wc -c
20
20 err
[1]+  Done                    wc -c err
```

That way you set up the listener for `stderr` output first and it blocks until it has a writer, which happens in the next command, using the syntax `2>err`. You can see that each `wc -c` got 20 characters of input.

Don't forget to clean up the fifo after you're done if you don't want it to hang around (i.e. `rm`). If the other command wants input on `stdin` and not a file arg, you can use input redirection like `wc -c < err` too.

Comment: Looks like the OP wanted *both* `stdout` and `stderr` to go to `command2`, which I initially missed. The above separates the two and send each separately to a command. I'll leave it though, as it might be useful to somebody.

Comment: No, I do not want both stdout and stderr to go to command2. stdout of command1 to command2, stderr of command1 to command3. command2 should not get stderr of command1

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time but...

@oHo's answer has the disadvantage of redirecting `command2` outputs to `stderr`. While @antak's answer may reverse the order of the outputs.

The solution below is likely to fix these problems by correctly redirecting `command2` and `command3` outputs and errors to, respectively, `stdout` and `stderr`, as expected and preserving order.

```
{ { command1 2>&3 | command2; } 3>&1 1>&4 | command3; } 4>&1
```

Of course, it also satisfies the OP's need to redirect output and errors from `command1` to, respectively, `command2` and `command3`.