# OS X / Linux: pipe into two processes?

Tags: macos, shell, unix, pipe

I know about

```
program1 | program2
```

and

```
program1 | tee outputfile | program2
```

but is there a way to feed program1's output into both program2 and program3?

Comment: I'm working about [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19125525/1765658)... As I'm only Debian user, feed-backs about other OS (especially MaxOS) are welcome!

Answer (score 35):

You can do this with `tee` and process substitution.

```
program1 | tee >(program2) >(program3)
```

The output of `program1` will be piped to whatever is inside `( )`, in this case `program2` and `program3`.

Comment: interesting -- which shell does that require? /bin/sh or bash or csh or ...?

Comment: `bash` is the shell I'm most familiar with, so I'm not certain of this feature (or similar syntax) in another shell.

Comment: After a cursory checkup in `sh` and `csh`, I can confirm this syntax doesn't work (it's fine in `bash` of course). But, as I said, a similar feature may merely require the correct syntax.

Comment: As `tee` copy to each *file*  **and also to standard output** , and as `>()` will be see by `tee` as *files*, you have to write: `prg1 | tee >(prg2) > >(prg3)` to **not** dump the ouptut of `prg1` on console (notice the supplementary `>`).

Comment: @StephenNiedzielski Care: In this case, `prg3` will read as *stdin*, the output of `prg2` concatenated to output of  `prg1`!!

Comment: I added an answer with a working demo. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48374970/117471

Comment: @F.Hauri: Could you tell why adding another `>` to the tee leads to `tee` not copying to standard output?

Comment: @AkshayArora This is basic redirection `> file` redirect STDOUT to file. It could be written: `1>file`. In this case: `prg1 | tee >(prg2) 1> >(prg3)`

Comment: @AkshayArora You may find some more sample, reading quietly [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19125525/1765658)

Comment: @F.Hauri for more clarity, I would just append `>/dev/null` at the end. The extra `>` is a bit confusing. `prg1 | tee >(prg2) >(prg3) >/dev/null`. But I agree, the answer could include the extra `> /dev/null`.

Comment: @chutz please read quietly [*More sophisticated demo* paragraph on my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19125525/1765658) and notice `> >(` on last *raw* `wc`!

Answer (score 26):

### Intro about *parallelisation*

This seem trivial, but doing this is not only possible, also doing so will generate *concurrent* or *simultaneous* process.

You may have to take care about some particular effects, like order of execution, exection time, etc.

There are some sample at end of this post.

### Compatible answer first

As this question is *flagged* [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) and [unix](/questions/tagged/unix), I will first give a *POSIX compatible* answer. (for *bashisms, go further*.)

Yes, there is a way to use *unnamed pipes*.

In this sample, I will generate a range of 100'000 numbers, randomize them and compress the result using 4 different compression tools to compare the compression ratio...

For this to I will first run the preparation:

```
GZIP_CMD=`which gzip`
BZIP2_CMD=`which bzip2`
LZMA_CMD=`which lzma`
XZ_CMD=`which xz`
MD5SUM_CMD=`which md5sum`
SED_CMD=`which sed`
```

**Note:** specifying full path to commands prevent some shell interpreter (like busybox) to run built-in compressor. And doing
way will ensure same syntax will run independently of os installation (paths could be different between MacOs, Ubuntu, RedHat, HP-Ux and so...).

The syntax `NN>&1` (where NN is a number between 3 and 63) do generate *unnamed pipe* who could by find at `/dev/fd/NN`. (The file descriptors 0 to 2 are already open for 0: STDIN, 1: STDOUT and 2: STDERR).

Try this (tested under [dash](/questions/tagged/dash), [busybox](/questions/tagged/busybox) and [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)) :

```
(((( seq 1 100000 | shuf | tee /dev/fd/4 /dev/fd/5 /dev/fd/6 /dev/fd/7 | $GZIP_CMD >/tmp/tst.gz ) 4>&1 | $BZIP2_CMD >/tmp/tst.bz2 ) 5>&1 | $LZMA_CMD >/tmp/tst.lzma ) 6>&1 | $XZ_CMD >/tmp/tst.xz ) 7>&1 | $MD5SUM_CMD
```

or more readable:

```
GZIP_CMD=`which gzip`
BZIP2_CMD=`which bzip2`
LZMA_CMD=`which lzma`
XZ_CMD=`which xz`
MD5SUM_CMD=`which md5sum`

(
  (
    (
      (
        seq 1 100000 |
          shuf |
          tee /dev/fd/4 /dev/fd/5 /dev/fd/6 /dev/fd/7 |
          $GZIP_CMD >/tmp/tst.gz
      ) 4>&1 |
        $BZIP2_CMD >/tmp/tst.bz2
    ) 5>&1 |
      $LZMA_CMD >/tmp/tst.lzma
  ) 6>&1 |
    $XZ_CMD >/tmp/tst.xz
) 7>&1 |
  $MD5SUM_CMD
2e67f6ad33745dc5134767f0954cbdd6  -
```

As `shuf` do random placement, if you try this, you must obtain different result,

```
ls -ltrS /tmp/tst.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 230516 oct  1 22:14 /tmp/tst.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 254811 oct  1 22:14 /tmp/tst.lzma
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 254892 oct  1 22:14 /tmp/tst.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 275003 oct  1 22:14 /tmp/tst.gz
```

but you must be able to compare *md5* checksums:

```
SED_CMD=`which sed`

for chk in gz:$GZIP_CMD bz2:$BZIP2_CMD lzma:$LZMA_CMD xz:$XZ_CMD;do
    ${chk#*:} -d < /tmp/tst.${chk%:*} |
        $MD5SUM_CMD |
        $SED_CMD s/-$/tst.${chk%:*}/
  done
2e67f6ad33745dc5134767f0954cbdd6  tst.gz
2e67f6ad33745dc5134767f0954cbdd6  tst.bz2
2e67f6ad33745dc5134767f0954cbdd6  tst.lzma
2e67f6ad33745dc5134767f0954cbdd6  tst.xz
```

### Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) features

Using some *bashims*, this could look nicer, for sample use `/dev/fd/{4,5,6,7}`, instead of `tee /dev/fd/4 /dev/fd/5 /...`

```
(((( seq 1 100000 | shuf | tee /dev/fd/{4,5,6,7} | gzip >/tmp/tst.gz ) 4>&1 |
   bzip2 >/tmp/tst.bz2 ) 5>&1 | lzma >/tmp/tst.lzma ) 6>&1 |
   xz >/tmp/tst.xz ) 7>&1 | md5sum
29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  -
```

will work same.

#### Final check

This won't create any file, but would let you compare size of a compressed range of sorted integers, between 4 different compression tool (for fun, I used 4 different way for formatting output):

```
(
  (
    (
      (
        (
          seq 1 100000 |
            tee /dev/fd/{4,5,6,7} |
              gzip |
              wc -c |
              sed s/^/gzip:\ \ / >&3
        ) 4>&1 |
          bzip2 |
          wc -c |
          xargs printf "bzip2: %s\n" >&3
      ) 5>&1 |
        lzma |
        wc -c |
        perl -pe 's/^/lzma:   /' >&3
    ) 6>&1 |
      xz |
      wc -c |
      awk '{printf "xz: %9s\n",$1}' >&3
  ) 7>&1 |
    wc -c
) 3>&1
gzip:  215157
bzip2: 124009
lzma:   17948
xz:     17992
588895
```

This demonstrate how to use *stdin* and *stdout* redirected in subshell **and** merged in console for final output.

#### Syntax `>(...)` and `<(...)`

Recent [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) versions permit a new syntax feature.

```
seq 1 100000 | wc -l
100000

seq 1 100000 > >( wc -l )
100000

wc -l < <( seq 1 100000 )
100000
```

As `|` is an *unnamed pipe* to `/dev/fd/0`, the syntax `<()` do generate temporary *unnamed pipe* with others file descriptor `/dev/fd/XX`.

```
md5sum <(zcat /tmp/tst.gz) <(bzcat /tmp/tst.bz2) <(
         lzcat /tmp/tst.lzma) <(xzcat /tmp/tst.xz)
29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  /dev/fd/63
29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  /dev/fd/62
29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  /dev/fd/61
29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  /dev/fd/60
```

#### More sophisticated demo

This require *GNU `file` utility* to be installed. Will determine command to be run by extension or file type.

```
for file in /tmp/tst.*;do
    cmd=$(which ${file##*.}) || {
        cmd=$(file -b --mime-type $file)
        cmd=$(which ${cmd#*-})
    }
    read -a md5 < <($cmd -d <$file|md5sum)
    echo $md5 \ $file
  done
29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  /tmp/tst.bz2
29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  /tmp/tst.gz
29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  /tmp/tst.lzma
29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  /tmp/tst.xz
```

This let you do same previous thing by following syntax:

```
seq 1 100000 |
    shuf |
        tee >(
            echo gzip. $( gzip | wc -c )
          )  >(
            echo gzip, $( wc -c < <(gzip))
          ) >(
            gzip  | wc -c | sed s/^/gzip:\ \ /
          ) >(
            bzip2 | wc -c | xargs printf "bzip2: %s\n"
          ) >(
            lzma  | wc -c | perl -pe 's/^/lzma:  /'
          ) >(
            xz    | wc -c | awk '{printf "xz: %9s\n",$1}'
          ) > >(
            echo raw: $(wc -c)
          ) |
        xargs printf "%-8s %9d\n"

raw:        588895
xz:         254556
lzma:       254472
bzip2:      231111
gzip:       274867
gzip,       274867
gzip.       274867
```

**Note** I used different way used to compute `gzip` compressed count.

**Note** Because this operation was done **simultaneously**, output order will depend on time required by each command.

#### Going further about parallelisation

If you run some multi-core or multi-processor computer, try to compare this:

```
i=1
time for file in /tmp/tst.*;do
    cmd=$(which ${file##*.}) || {
        cmd=$(file -b --mime-type $file)
        cmd=$(which ${cmd#*-})
    }
    read -a md5 < <($cmd -d <$file|md5sum)
    echo $((i++)) $md5 \ $file
  done |
cat -n
```

wich may render:

```
     1      1 29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  /tmp/tst.bz2
     2      2 29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  /tmp/tst.gz
     3      3 29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  /tmp/tst.lzma
     4      4 29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  /tmp/tst.xz

real    0m0.101s
```

with this:

```
time  (
    i=1 pids=()
    for file in /tmp/tst.*;do
        cmd=$(which ${file##*.}) || {
            cmd=$(file -b --mime-type $file)
            cmd=$(which ${cmd#*-})
        }
        (
             read -a md5 < <($cmd -d <$file|md5sum)
             echo $i $md5 \ $file
        ) & pids+=($!)
      ((i++))
      done
    wait ${pids[@]}
) |
cat -n
```

could give:

```
     1      2 29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  /tmp/tst.gz
     2      1 29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  /tmp/tst.bz2
     3      4 29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  /tmp/tst.xz
     4      3 29078875555e113b31bd1ae876937d4b  /tmp/tst.lzma

real    0m0.070s
```

where ordering depend on type used by each *fork*.

Comment: Further reading:  [`parallel.sh` *Parallelize stream processing using bash*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75548027/1765658)

Answer (score 2):

The `bash` manual mentions how it emulates the `>(...)` syntax using either named pipes or named file descriptors, so if you don't want to depend on `bash`, perhaps you could do that manually in your script.

```
mknod FIFO
program3 < FIFO &
program1 | tee FIFO | program2
wait
rm FIFO
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers introduce the concept. Here is an actual demonstration:

```
$ echo "Leeroy Jenkins" | tee >(md5sum > out1) >(sha1sum > out2) > out3

$ cat out1
11e001d91e4badcff8fe22aea05a7458  -

$ echo "Leeroy Jenkins" | md5sum
11e001d91e4badcff8fe22aea05a7458  -

$ cat out2
5ed25619ce04b421fab94f57438d6502c66851c1  -

$ echo "Leeroy Jenkins" | sha1sum
5ed25619ce04b421fab94f57438d6502c66851c1  -

$ cat out3
Leeroy Jenkins
```

Of course you can `> /dev/null` instead of out3.

Comment: In case subcommand output will be redirected, syntax  `> /dev/null` is useless!! Simplier way: `tee  <<<"Adam's familly" >(md5sum > out1) | sha1sum > out2`

Answer (score 1):

You can always try to save output of program1 to a file and then feed it into program2 and program3 input.

```
program1 > temp; program2 < temp; program3 < temp;
```

Comment: Yeah, I know (or `program1 | tee outputfile | program2; program3 <outputfile`) but I'd like to avoid if it's easy to do so.

Answer (score -1):

use `(;)` syntax...  try `ps aux | (head -n 1; tail -n 1)`

Comment: This don't answer to question: there is not two process, but only one, doing two successive things... And: This won't work on small system; try `seq 1 30 | (head ; tail)`! This don't work as expected!