# How do I redirect stdout to 2 files and a command and stderr to 2 files, a command and the console

Tags: bash, shell, unix, xcodebuild

I have this existing command:

```
xcodebuild | tee "$MY_TEMP_FILE_PATH" >> "$MY_LOG_FILE_PATH"
```

i.e.

```
stderr -> log file
          temp file
          normal console output

stdout -> log file 
          temp file
          (no normal console output)
```

I want to add on [OCUnit2JUnit](https://github.com/ciryon/OCUnit2JUnit).  Their example has this suffix: `2>&1 | ocunit2junit`.  However I want to integrate with my existing redirects, so the mapping will be:

```
stderr -> log file 
          temp file
          normal console output
          OCUnit2JUnit

stdout -> log file 
          temp file
          OCUnit2JUnit
          (no normal console output)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Pretty related: [osx/linux: pipes into two processes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10218103/1983854)

Comment: Why You need such redirection?

Comment: @Opal - `XCodeBuild` produces a lot of noisy output for the build server.  The only really useful thing is the `stderr` output.  However, occasionally it is useful to check the full log.  The next command I run filters the test output from `stdout` and deletes the temp file.  `OCUnit2JUnit` seems useful so I want to add this on.  Perhaps, the requirements can be simplified a little if this is not possible.