# One file input to two program in script

Tags: linux, bash, file, io-redirection

Hi I have a script that run two program

```
#Script file 
./prog1
./prog2
```

prog1 is a C program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  printf("prog1 running\n");
    int tmp;
    scanf("%d", &tmp);
    printf("%d\n", tmp+10);
    printf("prog1 ended\n");
    return 0;
}
```

prog 2 is a C program as well

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    printf("prog2 running\n");
    int tmp;
    scanf("%d\n", &tmp);
    printf("%d\n", tmp+10);
    printf("prog2 ended\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I run the command

./script < file

where file is

```
123
456
```

The output is

```
prog1 running
133
prog1 ended
prog2 running
10
prog2 ended
```

It seems like prog2 did not get the input from file, what is happening under the hood?

Will it be possible that prog2 took "\n" instead of a number?

Comment: There is a single input file descriptor shared between both processes (they inherited it from the script). The first process swallowed all the data. The second process then found the fd all the way at the end of the file already. If this needs to work you get to rewind the fd in one (or both) of the processes.

Comment: So you mean when I run script, a new file entry will be created for `script`, then script fork `prog1` `prog2` , so `prog1` `prog2` inherit the file descriptor from `script`. As `prog1` eat up all the input, the offset in file entry for this file point to the end of file, so `prog2` get nothing.

Comment: Yes, exactly that. This small shell script illustrates the concept: `{ echo "Line 1"; read -r line1; echo "$line1"; echo "Line 2"; read -r line2; echo "$line2"; } <<<$'content line 1\ncontent line 2'`

Answer (score 0):

Your script should be this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<&1
tee  >(./prog2 >&3) | ./prog1
```

This use the `tee` command to duplicate stdin and the recent `>()` bash feature to open a temporary filedescriptor. (the use of filedesriptor 3 is done to split the stdout without parallelism).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218103/osx-linux-pipes-into-two-processes) to read the whole story.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` reads **buffered** input.  So when your first program reads from `stdin`, it speculatively reads ahead all the available input to make future reads from `stdin` faster (through avoiding having to make so many system calls).  When the second program runs, there's no input left, and (since you failed to check the result of `scanf()`) you end up with 0 in `tmp`.

You should be able to modify the buffering strategy in your application (at the expense of speed) using the `setvbuf()` standard function.