# Redirect stdout of a process to more than one pipe

Tags: c, pipe, stdout, stdin

I want to execute a process with exevcp (let's say ls -l). I want the output of that to go to the input of more than one process. I don't if that is possible with pipes. Can someone help me ?

Comment: You may need to create a memory queue to keep the output  and develop an API to feed the input to multiple processes.

Comment: Check out how `tee` works: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tee.c

Comment: using the shell, in linux, you can use `tee`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at how `tee` works, as suggested in the comments, might be the way to go. However, for simplicity, why not use a shell and tee itself wrapped around your process?

```
your_process | tee >(process1) >(process2)
```

For reference: [OS X / Linux: pipe into two processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10218282/1672565)