# More than one pipe makes output blank in streams of text

Tags: shell, pipe, stdout, tail, youtube-dl

This question is NOT related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43970430/redirect-stdout-of-a-process-to-more-than-one-pipe) as I don't want to redirect the output to more than one process. Instead, I want to pipe an output twice like you'd normally do, like this:

```sh
$ echo "piping twice" | cut -d 'p' -f 3 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
ing
```

This works as expected!
However, trying the same with `tail -f` fails:

```sh
$ echo "piping twice" > somefile

# The first test passes: 
$ tail -f somefile | cut -d 'p' -f 3
ing twice

# The second test shows nothing:
$ tail -f somefile | cut -d 'p' -f 3 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

I'm using tail as a reproducible example, but I'm actually trying to parse the progress output of `youtube-dl`, and more than one piping always results in blank lines.
Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
tail -f somefile | stdbuf -oL cut -d 'p' -f 3| cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

As most Linux programs will use line buffering if `stdout` is connecting to a TTY and full buffering otherwise. You can use `stdbuf` to force line buffering.