# Tee to commands only, not stdout

Tags: bash, tee

I already know how to use `tee` with process substitution to send output to various commands, *and* stdout, eg

```sh
command0 | tee >(command1) >(command2)
```

With the above line, stdout will be composed of interleaved lines from `command0`, `command1`, and `command2`.

Is there a way to prevent tee from writing to stdout, without removing the output of any commands it pipes to? So for the example above, for stdout to only have output from `command1` and `command2`?
Most answers relating to `tee`ing without stdout are only writing directly to files, and recommend using something like this:

```sh
command0 | tee file1 file2 >/dev/null
```

But with process substitution, that would consume all output from the other commands too.

```sh
command0 | tee >(command1) >(command2) >/dev/null
```

Is there some way to tell `tee` not to print to stdout, or to only consume the output directly from `tee`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
( command0 | tee >(command1 1>&3 ) | command2 ) 3>&1
```

It redirects the stdout of command1 to pipe 3, so that command2 sees only the original source. At end, you redirect pipe 3 to stdout again.

Use this to test it:

```
( echo test | tee >( sed 's/^/1 /' >&3 )  | sed 's/^/2 /' ) 3>&1
```

The output is unordered and in my case:

```
2 test
1 test
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218103/os-x-linux-pipe-into-two-processes#comment28283588_10218282) and an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19125525/6112457) that use an extra `>`, but don't really explain why it does what it does. It seems like it is redirecting output *somewhere* but all I can tell so far is that it does what I'm looking for. This works:

```sh
command0 | tee > >(command1) >(command2)
command0 | tee >(command1) > >(command2)
```

it appears not to matter where the extra `>` is, so long as it is before at least one of the arguments to `tee`. So this will not work:

```sh
command0 | tee >(command1) >(command2) >
```

Without knowing what this is called, and with no further leads, I can't explain further.

Comment: `> >(foo)` redirects to the [*process substitution*](http://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) `>(foo)`. Process substitution involves replacing the `>(foo)` with the path to a file representing `foo`'s stdin, so think of it as `tee > /some/stdin1 /some/stdin2`, or equivalently, `tee /some/stdin2 > /some/stdin1`, which should make it clear what's happening.

Comment: That makes me think that it would send an additional copy of the piped output to the process, but I know empirically that that isn't the case. The linked documentation doesn't seem to mention this pattern anywhere either.

Comment: Oh, are you saying that `>(foo)` is no longer an argument to tee in the case of `> >(foo)`, but just a redirection in the middle of the command?

Comment: Yes, `> >(foo)` is a redirection in the middle of the command. Just think of `>(foo)` as a path to a file (a special file, but a file nonetheless).

Comment: I just realised, I'm not sure how I came to the conclusion that `>/dev/null` fails in this case, because it doesn't. It only captures the output from `tee`'s stdout, and not the processes it sends output to.