# Pipe output to two different commands

Tags: bash, pipe, tee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [osx/linux: pipes into two processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218103/osx-linux-pipes-into-two-processes)

Is there a way to pipe the output from one command into the input of two other commands, running them simultaneously?

Something like this:

```
$ echo 'test' |(cat) |(cat)
test
test
```

The reason I want to do this is that I have a program which receives an FM radio signal from a USB SDR device, and outputs the audio as raw PCM data (like a .wav file but with no header.)  Since the signal is not music but POCSAG pager data, I need to pipe it to a decoder program to recover the pager text.  However I also want to listen to the signal so I know whether any data is coming in or not.  (Otherwise I can't tell if the decoder is broken or there's just no data being broadcast.)  So as well as piping the data to the pager decoder, I also need to pipe the same data to the `play` command.

Currently I only know how to do one - either pipe it to the decoder and read the data in silence, or pipe it to `play` and hear it without seeing any decoded text.

How can I pipe the same data to both commands, so I can read the text and hear the audio?

I can't use `tee` as it only writes the duplicated data to a file, but I need to process the data in real-time.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands for example

Comment: @Mat: Can you repost your answer here?  That works for me and seems to be a really nice solution.

Comment: Yes I think this is a duplicate of that one

Comment: If you're just trying to save tying something multiple times in a command then the most simple solution would be `x=myoutput && command one $x && command two $x`

Comment: @tumelo: The question is about passing the data in on standard input, but your example only places the data in a command line parameter, it doesn't pass it to the command on `stdin`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It should be ok if you use both `tee` and `mkfifo`.

```
mkfifo pipe
cat pipe | (command 1) &
echo 'test' | tee pipe | (command 2)
```

Comment: This is very useful to save IO when e.g. making backups. One can pipe the `tar` output through `pv` and through `sha512sum` before writing it, avoiding double or even triple reads/writes to/from disk.

Comment: by the way, since this can get very confusing, if you want to fail on a certain command, you have to write `{ somecommand || errorhandler; } | tee pipe | command2`, or even `{ somecommand || errorhandlerforcommand1; } | tee pipe | command2 || errorhandlerforcommand2`, as both `somecommand || errorhandler | tee pipe | command2` and `somecommand | tee pipe | command2 || errorhandler` are not handling errors of `somecommand` as one might expect!

Comment: Finally, to pipe just `stderr` into e.g. a log handler, you must add `2> >(errlogger)` *before* the `||` as so: `{ somecommand 2> >(errlogger) || errorhandlerforcommand1; } | tee pipe | command2`.  
Everything else will explode in your face.

Comment: `cat pipe |` should be replace by `<pipe`. Is the common way to make a command read input from file or pipe instead of stdin.

Answer (score 32):

### Recent [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) present `>(command)` syntax:

```bash
echo "Hello world." | tee >(sed 's/^/1st: /')  >(sed 's/^/2nd cmd: /') >/dev/null
```

May return:

```
2nd cmd: Hello world.
1st: Hello world.
```

#### download `somefile.ext`, save them, compute md5sum and sha1sum:

```bash
wget -O - http://somewhere.someland/somepath/somefile.ext |
    tee somefile.ext >(md5sum >somefile.md5) | sha1sum >somefile.sha1
```

or

```bash
wget -O - http://somewhere.someland/somepath/somefile.ext |
    tee >(md5sum >somefile.md5) >(sha1sum >somefile.sha1) >somefile.ext
```

### Old answer

There is a way to do that via unnamed pipe (tested under linux):

```bash
 (( echo "hello" |
         tee /dev/fd/5 |
             sed 's/^/1st occure: /' >/dev/fd/4
    ) 5>&1 |
    sed 's/^/2nd command: /'
 ) 4>&1
```

give:

```
2nd command: hello
1st occure: hello
```

as well:

```bash
echo "hello" | (
     ( tee /dev/fd/5 |
           sed 's/^/1st occure: /' >/dev/fd/4
     ) 5>&1 |
     sed 's/^/2nd command: /'
     ) 4>&1
```

This sample will let you download `somefile.ext`, save them, compute his md5sum and compute his sha1sum:

```bash
(( wget -O - http://somewhere.someland/somepath/somefile.ext |
    tee somefile.ext /dev/fd/5 |
    md5sum >/dev/fd/4
  ) 5>&1 |
  sha1sum
) 4>&1
```

or

```bash
wget -O - http://somewhere.someland/somepath/somefile.ext |
  (( tee /dev/fd/5 somefile.ext | md5sum >/dev/fd/4 ) 5>&1 | sha1sum ) 4>&1
```

or event more usefull:

```bash
url='http://ftp.uio.no/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd'
read -r file < <(
    wget -qO - "$url" |
        sed -ne 's/.*href="\(debian-[1-9]\+\..*\.iso\)".*/\1/p')
wget -O - "$url/$file" | (
    ( tee /dev/fd/5 "$file" |
        sha256sum |
            sed -ne "h;s/-/$file/;w ${file%.*}.sha256" \
                 -e 'x;s/-/SHA256/;w /dev/fd/4'
    ) 5>&1 |
        sha512sum |
            sed -e "h;s/-/$file/;w ${file%.*}.sha512" \
                -e 'x;s/-/SHA512/'
) 4>&1
```

Will produce 3 files **and** output two lines:

```
64d727dd5785ae5fcfd3ae8ffbede5f40cca96f1580aaa2820e8b99dae989d94  SHA256
0262488ce2cec6d95a6c9002cfba8b81ac0d1c29fe7993aa5af30f81cecad3eb66558b9d8689a86b57bf12b8cbeab1e11d128a53356b288d48e339bb003dace5  SHA512
```

Which could be compared with:

```bash
for i in 256 512;do wget -qO - "$url/SHA${i}SUMS" | grep $file;done
```

```
64d727dd5785ae5fcfd3ae8ffbede5f40cca96f1580aaa2820e8b99dae989d94  debian-12.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso
0262488ce2cec6d95a6c9002cfba8b81ac0d1c29fe7993aa5af30f81cecad3eb66558b9d8689a86b57bf12b8cbeab1e11d128a53356b288d48e339bb003dace5  debian-12.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso
```

Comment: Read my [more detailled answer on this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19125525/1765658)

Comment: Or my [`parallel.sh` *Parallelize stream processing using bash*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75548027/1765658)

Comment: If this multiple- >() syntax works for `tee`, why can't it work even _without_ the tee?

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike This syntax is *bashism* and work with any command! The purpose of `tee`  is to multiplicate output to many targets.

Comment: But why do we need tee for that, if we can use >() ? i.e. why not just `echo "Hello world."  >(sed 's/^/1st: /')  >(sed 's/^/2nd cmd: /')` ?

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike Because `echo` use your *STDOUT* for output, which is unique! You can't redirect any OUTPUT more than once! `tee` is intended to multiply output to as many target you address, plus *STDOUT*.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe take a look at `tee` command. What it does is simply print its input to a file, but it also prints its input to the standard output. So something like:

```
echo "Hello" | tee try.txt | <some_command>
```

Will create a file with content "Hello" AND also let "Hello" (flow through the pipeline) end up as `<some_command>`'s STDIN.

Comment: *I can't use tee as it only writes the duplicated data to a file, but I need to process the data in real-time.*

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood you. Don't you need the raw data to be passed to play?

Comment: @izomorphius: I need to hear the data "live" - if it is redirected to a file, there will be a delay, so it will no longer be live.  Also the file will grow in size until I run out of disk space, if I listen for a long time!

Comment: But you can use tee to redirect the output to a pipe. It does not have to be a file.

Comment: @izomorphius: Ah yes, but I had forgotten about pipes and that was conveniently missing from your answer :-P