# Shell - Pipe to multiple commands in a file

Tags: bash, shell, tee

I want to run 2 commands on a piped-in input and want to print (to stdout) the output of both.

Each command is a combination of grep, sed and awk.

Both these commands must reside in a single .sh file.

Sample commands:

```
cat mult_comm.sh       
sed 's/World/Boy/g'|grep Boy ; grep World

# Input
cat input.log
Hello World

# This command HAS to work EXACTLY like this
cat input.log | bash mult_comm.sh
```

Expected output

```
Hello Boy
Hello World
```

Actual output

```
Hello Boy
```

I tried using tee

```
cat mult_comm.sh
tee >(sed 's/World/Boy/g'|grep Boy) | grep World
```

But this gives only

```
Hello World
```

I can modify the .sh file as I want but the piped command can't be changed. Any ideas?

This is similar to [OS X / Linux: pipe into two processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218103/osx-linux-pipes-into-two-processes) and [Pipe output to two different commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107783/pipe-output-to-two-different-commands), but I can't figure out how to use named pipes inside the script.

Comment: Is it cheating to do it with just sed?  `sed -n 'h;s/World/Boy/g;/Boy/p;x;/World/p' < input.log`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you execute

```
tee >(some_command)
```

bash creates a subshell to run `some_command`. The subshell's `stdin` is assigned to the reading half of a pipe. bash leaves the name of this pipe on the command line, so that `tee` will pump its input into the pipe. The subshell's `stdout` and `stderr` are left unchanged, so they are still the same as `tee`'s.

So, when you execute

```
tee >(some_command) | some_other_command
```

Now, bash first creates a process to run `tee`, and assigns its `stdout` to the writing half of a pipe, and another process to run `some_other_command`, with its `stdin` assigned to the reading half of the same pipe. Then it creates another process to run `some_command`, as above, assigning its `stdin` to the reading half of another pipe, and leaving its `stdout` and `stderr` unchanged. However, `stdout` has already been redirected to `some_other_command`, and that's what `some_command` inherits.

In your actual example,

```
tee >(sed 's/World/Boy/g'|grep Boy) | grep World
```

we end up with:

```
                  -->  sed 's/World/Boy/g' -->  grep Boy --
                 /                                         \
input --> tee --<                                           \
                 \                                           \
                  ----------------------------------------------> grep World
```

In one of the questions linked in the OP, there is a (non-accepted but correct) answer by [F. Hauri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107783/pipe-output-to-two-different-commands/13108173#13108173), which I've adapted here:

```
echo Hello World |
((tee /dev/fd/5 | grep World >/dev/fd/4) \
           5>&1 | sed 's/World/Boy/' | grep Boy) 4>&1
```

It takes a little practice to read bashisms like the above. The important part is that

```
( commands ) 5>&1
```

Creates a subshell (`( )`) and gives that subshell an fd numbered 5, initially copied from `stdout` (`5>&1`). Inside the subshell, `/dev/fd/5` refers to that fd. Within the subshell, it is possible to redirect `stdout`, but that will happen after stdout is copied to fd5.

Comment: This makes sense except that I am not so hot with file descriptors. Any idea why I would be getting:tee: /dev/fd/5: No such file or directory

Comment: @SANDeveloper: You need to do it exactly as shown. `(tee /dev/fd/5 ... ) 5>&1`. Here the `( ) 5>&1` creates a subshell with fd5 made a duplicate of fd1. Inside that subshell, you can use /dev/fd/5. Similarly with /dev/fd/4, which is generated with `(...) 4>&1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pee(1)` – in Debian/Ubuntu it's available in the package `moreutils`.

Usage for your example, somewhat more readable than the magic redirection

```
echo Hello World | pee 'grep World' 'sed "s/World/Boy/" | grep Boy'
```