# Pipe output to two different commands not interlaced

Tags: shell, pipe, stdout, tee

Using techniques mentioned here ([Pipe output to two different commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107783/pipe-output-to-two-different-commands)) we can split a stdout into multiple processes.

```
expensive_command | tee >(proc_1) >(proc_2) | proc_3
```

my problem is this interlaces the output.

Is there a way to copy the stdout but force proc_2 to block until proc_1 finishes?

I'm thinking something like

```
expensive_command | tee >(proc_1) | wait for EOF | tee >(proc_2) ...
```

Comment: you could do something like cmd > file && cat file |
 tee >(proc_1) && cat file | tee >(proc_2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a fifo as a cheap lock. Have `proc1` write to it after it completes, and wait until a read from the fifo succeeds before running `proc2`.

```
mkfifo cheap_lock
expensive_command | tee >(proc1; echo foo > cheap_lock) \
                        >(read < cheap_lock; proc2 ) | proc3
```

(Of course, it's your responsibility to ensure that no other processes try to read from or write to cheap_lock.)

Comment: hard to choose an answer between konsolebox and chepner since they both are well thought out but in the end I am using chepner's solution so he gets the vote.

Comment: While you can only select one answer, you can still upvote both.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a buffer holder that would release the output once data from input reaches eof like

```
expensive_command | awk '{ a[i++] = $0 }END{for (i = 0; i in a; ++i) { print a[i] | "tee temp.txt" } }'
```

Only that `awk` does not support process substitution.

In bash you can do:

```
readarray -t lines <(expressive_command | tee >(proc_1))
printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}" | tee >(proc_2)
```

Depending on the peak data size of your output from `expressive_command` or version of your Bash, the command may require adjustments. You can also consider using another language.

Add: You can also use **[stdbuf](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman1/stdbuf.1.html).** It runs command *with modified buffering operations for its standard streams*.