# Split pipe into two and paste the results together?

Tags: bash, command-line, pipe

I want to pipe the output of the command into two commands and `paste` the results together. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107783/pipe-output-to-two-different-commands) and similar ones suggesting using `tee` but I'm not sure how to make it work as I'd like it to.

My problem (simplified):

Say that I have a `myfile.txt` with keys and values, e.g.

```
key1   /path/to/file1
key2   /path/to/file2
```

What I am doing right now is

```bash
paste \
  <( cat myfile.txt | cut -f1 ) \
  <( cat myfile.txt | cut -f2 | xargs wc -l )
```

and it produces

```
key1 23
key2 42
```

The problem is that `cat myfile.txt` is repeated here (in the real problem it's a heavier operation). Instead, I'd like to do something like

```bash
cat myfile.txt | tee \
  <( cut -f1 ) \
  <( cut -f2 | xargs wc -l ) \
  | paste
```

But it doesn't produce the expected output. Is it possible to do something similar to the above with pipes and standard command-line tools?

Comment: How about caching the result of the *"heavier operation"* in order to avoid the problem of doing it twice?

Comment: @MarkSetchell definitely it's a practical solution, and this is what I'm considering, but I was curious if split-and-merge is possible via pipes?

Comment: what about `fifo`?  `mkfifo /tmp/fifo && cat myfile.txt | tee >(cut -f1 >/tmp/fifo) | cut -f2 | xargs wc -l | paste /tmp/fifo - && rm /tmp/fifo`

Comment: I think it produces `key1 23 /path/to/file` and `key2 42 /path/to/file2`, due to how `wc -l` works. ;-) But that’s just a detail. (One can do `wc -l < /path/to/file` to _not_ let `wc` know about the file name, but it’s harder to set up with `xargs`. On a similar note, you do not need any of the `cat` commands, that’s a clear [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) case. (`cat` is for con`cat`enation; not needed for a single file.)

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek thanks for nitpicking on the details of a toy code example produced for illustrating the problem, which was stripped of all the details that are irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @Tim Obviously, it was *not* _“stripped of all the details that are irrelevant to the problem”_, as my nitpick suggests.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question about pipes, but you can use AWK to solve your problem:

```
$ printf %s\\n 1 2 3 > file1.txt
$ printf %s\\n 1 2 3 4 5 > file2.txt
$ cat > myfile.txt <<EOF
key1    file1.txt
key2    file2.txt
EOF
$ cat myfile.txt | awk '{ ("wc -l " $2) | getline size; sub(/ .+$/,"",size); print $1, size }'
key1 3
key2 5
```

On each line we first we run `wc -l $2` and save the result into a variable. Not sure about yours, but on my system `wc -l` includes the filename in the output, so we strip it with `sub()` to match your example output. And finally, we print the `$1` field (key) and the size we got from `wc -l` command.

Also, can be done with shell, now that I think about it:

```bash
cat myfile.txt | while read -r key value; do
  printf '%s %s\n' "$key" "$(wc -l "$value" | cut -d' ' -f1)"
done
```

Or more generally, by piping to two commands and using `paste`, therefore answering the question:

```bash
cat myfile.txt | while read -r line; do
  printf %s "$line" | cut -f1
  printf %s "$line" | cut -f2 | xargs wc -l | cut -d' ' -f1
done | paste - -
```

P.S. The use of `cat` here is useless, I know. But it's just a placeholder for the real command.

Comment: Nice, I like it (+1). I didn't think of the good old awk.