# How to pipe stderr into stdin?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, upstart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pipe stdout and stderr to two different processes in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112979/pipe-stdout-and-stderr-to-two-different-processes-in-shell-script)

I have a program which writes to stdout and stderr, I want to pipe the stdout into the stdin of the `logger` command and pipe the stderr into the stdin of another `logger` command where the facility, priority and tag are different from the first `logger` command.

This command is run in the exec stanza of an upstart script on Ubuntu.
Also I tried with subshells but it did not work.

Any idea how could I do this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: here is a possible solution (not mine, therefore not an answer) http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=201837

Comment: @ammoQ - I see no problem in posting a link as an answer (with a precis in case the linked article disappears). It's an answer after all, and you found it :-)

Comment: @BrianAgnew: Since I don't know if it is a good solution, or even works at all, I rather don't post something I have just googled as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
logger 2>&1 | logger
```

Explanation: `logger 2>&1` will redirect the standard error (file descriptor 2) to the standard output (file descriptor 1), then `| logger` will pipe that to the standard input of another instance of the `logger` command.

Comment: I'm not sure that's right. I think stderr should go to somewhere distinct from stdout ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew I don't know if that's possible (using simple shell commands at least). How would you do that?

Comment: Hi @BrianAgnew, thanks for posting. But logger doesn't output anything. logger is an utility command to write message to syslog. I want to write stderr and stdout of my program into logger, but on logger with different facility, priority and tags. I want something like this `program 1> logger -p local0.info -t test_info 2> logger -p local0.error -t test_error`, unfortunately redirection is only for files.