# Redirect stdout and stderr to different program without changing exit code

Tags: linux, bash

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112979/pipe-stdout-and-stderr-to-two-different-processes-in-shell-script) basically asks the same question but I want an additional requirement, which is: the exit code should be unchanged.

The accepted answer uses pipe, so the exit code is no longer the exit code of `command1`.

Command set `pipefail` doesn't fit my need as I don't want to affect the behavior when executing `command1`, which might be a compound Bash command itself.

I tried the following approach, but the output is not as expected:

```
[hidden]$ (echo haha; echo hehe 1>&2) > >(while read -r x; do echo "xx $x"; done)
2> >(while read -r y; do echo "yy $y"; done)
xx haha
xx yy hehe
```

Can anyone tell why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

```
command1 3>&1 4>&2 1> >(command2 1>&3 2>&4) 2> >(command3 1>&3 2>&4)
```

In this way, no matter `command2` and `command3` output to stdout or stderr, there will be no problem.

Comment: With your example in the question, my answer gives the exact output as this, and is less verbose

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get `xx yy hehe` in your output because `yy hehe` line from 2nd while loop is also being written on stdout and being fed to the first `while read` loop thus becoming `xx yy hehe`

You can use this script:

```
{ echo haha; echo hehe >&2; } 2> >(while read -r y; do echo "yy $y"; done) > >(while read -r x; do echo "xx $x"; done)
yy hehe
xx haha
```

---

**EDIT:** To show how **exit code remains unchanged** this way:

```
{ echo haha; ls hehe >&2; } 2> >(while read -r y; do echo "yy $y"; done) > >(while read -r x; do echo "xx $x"; done); echo "exit status: $?"
xx haha
yy ls: cannot access hehe: No such file or directory
exit status: 2
```

---

**EDIT2** To show how to use alternate file descriptors for redirecting:

```
{ date >&5; ls hehe >&6 2>&6; } \
5> >(while read -r x; do echo "xx: $x"; done) \
6> >(while read -r y; do echo "yy: $y"; done); \
echo "exit status: $?"; 5>&- && 6>&-
xx: Sat Dec  6 03:25:20 EST 2014
yy: ls: cannot access hehe: No such file or directory
exit status: 2
```

Comment: if the two process substitutions output to stderr, then it still has problem.  Try `{ echo haha; echo hehe >&2; } 2> >(while read -r y; do echo "yy $y"; done >&2) > >(while read -r x; do echo "xx $x"; done >&2)`

Comment: @icando: I did't get your comment. You asked how to redirect stdout and stderr separately and my suggested command does that. Now if those commands redirect to stderr again then of course same read script (`yy` in that case) will get data again from fd `2`. I don't see anything unexpected in this case.

Comment: @Jasen: No where in this script `exit` code is tampered. Run this command: `echo haha; ls hehe >&2; } 2> >(while read -r y; do echo "yy $y"; done) > >(while read -r x; do echo "xx $x"; done); echo $?` and will you will see exit code `2` which is originating from `ls` command.

Answer (score 0):

[This was answered](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2012-01/msg00036) back in 2012. The reason is because the substitutions are
not all done at the same time. A workaround is to keep stderr with stderr.

```
foo > >(baz) 2> >(qux 1>&2)
```