# Send stderr and stdout to a function as variable and check type

Tags: bash

I am redirecting the output of a script to a function I've written by using `2>&1 | MyFunction`

This works great. However, I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to determine if the variable being passed is `STDOUT` or `STDERR` in `MyFunction`

Ex:

```
function MyFunction {
    while read line; do
        read IN
        echo "LOG: $IN" >> $LOG_FILE;
    done    
}
```

Is there some way the perform a check on the passed variable if it is an instance of either `STDOUT` or `STDERR` so I can perform conditional rules based upon it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
# call the function like:
# cmd | log err
# cmd | log info    
log() {
    type="${1}"
    while read -r line ; do
        if [ "${type}" = "err" ] ; then
            echo "EE ${line}"
        else
            echo "II ${line}"
        fi
    done
}

# Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9113604/171318
# Use another file descriptor to separate between stdout and stderr
{ stdbuf -eL -oL cmd 2>&3 | log info ; } 3>&1 1>&2 | log err
# PS: ^ stdbuf makes sure that lines in output are in order
```

Answer (score 2):

The pipe will convey standard output (STDOUT) data.
The `2>&1` redirects the standard error ("2") to the file descriptor "1", which is the standard output.

This means the following line :
`myCommand 2>&1 | MyFunction`
can be read as "Run myCommand, redirect the standard error to the standard output, and run MyFunction on the output (which is standard error + standard output)"

Once you've written `2>&1`, there is no way to know which line was initially sent to STDOUT or STDERR.

Comment: Huh! Your last line probably what he is looking for. `:-)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It gave me a better understanding of the usage of 2>&1.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, no. If you don't need to be compatible to other shells than Bash, you can use a bit of trickery in Bash to add a prefix to every line; for example

```
bash$ { perl -le 'print "oops"; die' 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') > >(sed 's/^/stdout: /'); } 2>&1 | nl
 1  stdout: oops
 2  stderr: Died at -e line 1.
```

As you can see, the output from the two `sed` processes is recombined into standard output, which is then piped as standard input to the line numbering program `nl`.  The braces group the commands so that the final redirection `2>&1` doesn't directly affect the Perl process.