# howto send stderr and stdout through separate grep filters?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

Trying to run a command that produces a lot of stdout and stderr.
Need a way to filter most of the stderr messages.

Something like

```
command 1> grep "a" 2> grep "b"
```

alternative how to only grep stderr but also see stdout.

Comment: [This answer]
 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31151808/9200529) in particular is thorough and useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
{ command 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | grep "b"; } 3>&1 1>&2 | grep "a"
```

Note:  the above is adapted from [*antak*'s answer to "pipe stdout and stderr to two different processes in shell script?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31151808/9200529), with `grep`s replacing its more abstract names.  For how it works, see that answer.
(Nevertheless, lazy coders who need `grep` might prefer a more specific answer like this.)

A useful util for distinguishing *stdout* from *stderr* is [`annotate-output`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/annotate-output.1.html), (install the ["*devscripts*" package](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/devscripts.1.html)), which sends *stderr* and *stdin* both to *stdout* along with helpful little prefixes:

```
annotate-output wc -c /bin/bash /bin/nosuchshell
```

Output:

```
00:29:06 I: Started wc -c /bin/bash /bin/nosuchshell
00:29:06 E: wc: /bin/nosuchshell: No such file or directory
00:29:06 O: 1099016 /bin/bash
00:29:06 O: 1099016 total
00:29:06 I: Finished with exitcode 1
```

That output could be parsed separately using `sed`, `awk`, or even a `tee` and a few `grep`s.

Comment: the grep filter, re-orders the output though, the annotate-output is real handy.