# How to use nohup with curly braces?

Tags: bash, nohup

I try to run the following command ([ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112979/pipe-stdout-and-stderr-to-two-different-processes-in-shell-script)) using nohup, which basically separates stdout and stderr into two processes.

```
{ foo 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | sed -u 's/^/err: /'; } 3>&1 1>&2 | sed -u 's/^/out: /'
```

The foo script is like below.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
   echo a
   echo b >&2
   sleep 1
done
```

This is the test result.

```
$ nohup { foo 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | sed -u 's/^/err: /'; } 3>&1 1>&2 | sed -u 's/^/out: /' >/dev/null 2>&1 &
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

Comment: Try: `nohup bash -c "{ foo 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | sed -u 's/^/err: /'; } 3>&1 1>&2" | sed -u 's/^/out: /' >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: Or instead use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49299040/2868801) which works fine with nohup.

Comment: What's the goal of this: `... | sed -u 's/^/out: /' >/dev/null 2>&1` ??? Why did you run `sed` for dropping his output?? Maybe `nohup foo &>/dev/null &` will do your job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's syntatically impossible. But you can wrap your `{}` in a `sh -c cmd`:

```bash
nohup sh -c 'foo 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | sed -u "s/^/err: /"'
```

Notice I change the single quote for sed to double quote.